# Postgres Get Count of Email Domains

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have user email entries in my db and I want to see how many users have the domain `@gmail.com` and how many users have the domain `@yahoo.com` and so on. What would be the best way to do that?

Right now I am going through and running the query manually one by one by doing:

```
select email from "user" where email ilike '%@gmail.com';
```

Comment: You can do a substr operation and then equate, it will be a little bit faster. Also, you can create an index on the email column to speed up the query further

Answer (score 52, accepted):

My first idea would be to extract the domain and group by that:

```
select substring(email from '@(.*)$') as domain, count(*)
from "user"
group by domain
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case function `split_part` can be used:

```
select split_part(email, '@', 2) "domain", count(*)
from emails 
group by "domain";
```

[PostgreSQL split_part fiddle](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/ee106abb391b8c12cf94d74f46d56d24/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach:

```sql
select dm.domain, count(*) as total
from (
         select lower(right(email, char_length(email) - position('@' in email))) as domain
         from "user"
         group by  domain, email)dm
group by dm.domain
order by total desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substring(email from '@(.*)$') as domain, count(*)
from  pytest.emps
group by domain

SELECT distinct(split_part (email,'@',2) ) as domain_name FROM pytest.emps 

SELECT split_part (email,'@',2) as domain_name FROM pytest.emps group by domain_name
```